# Filtering in pandas: excluding rows that contain part of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following code will select observations from a pandas dataframe that include the word Elstar in the type column.

```
df[df['type'].str.contains('Elstar')
```

How should this code be edited so it excludes those that contain the word Elstar? I tried adding a ~ in front of the filter however this does not have the desired effect, as it results in:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

I have found solutions where the string should not match an exact other string but in my case part of the value should not match.

Comment: Use `df[~df['type'].str.contains('Elstar', na=False)]`

Comment: @jezrael why is this required? I am sure there are no na values. It works btw. just would like to know why.

Comment: No, if you are sure not `NaN`s then be free omit `na` parameter.